# Does tikz work in wrapfigure environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure

I tried to use tikz in `wrap figure`

```
\begin{prob} % Line 86
% Explain my problem to solve. % Line 87 to 91
\begin{proof}[answer] % Line 92
% Solving problem % Line 93
\begin{wrapfigure} % Line 94
\begin{tikzpicture} % Line 95
% Writing some tikz code using \filldraw. % Line 96 to 105
\end{tikzpicture} % Line 106
\end{wrapfigure} % Line 107
\end{proof} % Line 108
\end{prob} % Line 109
```

and received the errors below:
[image]

Comment: Yes, TikZ works inside `wrapfigure`. However, you should read the documentation of `wrapfig`: the placement (right/left) and width has to be specified, e.g. `\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\linewidth}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please *always* post *complete* small documents, and post code sections not images of code.

However it appears from your fragment that you have omitted the arguments to `wrapfigure`

the line

```
\begin{wrapfigure}
```

should be something like

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
```

Comment: Help full quick answer. sorry for immediate question.